# ProjectLibre in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Can anyone help me install Project Libre on Ubuntu 16.04? 
I tried source forge, but I could not find the .deb to install.

Answer (score 7):

You can download the deb files (for different versions) [from SourceForge here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/projectlibre/files/ProjectLibre/).

Then use `sudo dpkg -i <name-of-deb-file>.deb` to install.

The latest `.deb` file is [this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/projectlibre/files/ProjectLibre/1.6.2/projectlibre_1.6.2-1.deb/download).

Answer (score 2):

You can install ProjectLibre automatically with these commands (the URL address must be updated to the latest version).  Just cut and paste the 3 commands into a terminal one at a time:

```
URL=https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/projectlibre/ProjectLibre/1.7/projectlibre_1.7.0-1.deb

wget -q ${URL} -O /tmp/${URL##*/}
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/${URL##*/}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also just download a ZIP version (say projectlibre-1.7.0.zip) from https://sourceforge.net/projects/projectlibre/files/ProjectLibre/

then unzip it to any folder,

run "chmod +x projectlibre.sh" in that folder,

then you can run it via "./projectlibre.sh"

works on Ubuntu 17